# Unit vector c perpendicular

Tags: vector-spaces

Find a unit vector $c$ perpendicular to both of the vectors $a = 0j + 1j - k$ and $b = 2i + 2j – k$.

Just need steps/hints or even the solution would help me check if I go it right.

Comment: Please don't yell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1**: If vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are perpendicular, then $\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}=0$. Thus you can make 3 simultaneous equations using $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c}=\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{c}=0$ and $|\mathbf{c}|=1$.

**Hint 2**: $\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}$, the cross product of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, is perpendicular to both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. Normalize it.

Answer (score 0):

A vector $\vec{c}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ exactly when $\vec{c}\cdot \vec{a} = 0$ and $\vec{c}\cdot \vec{b} = 0$ (dot product). You will be able to find lots of vectors satisfying these two equations, but there will be only two that are unit vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cross product. It takes two 3 dimensional vectors and produces a vector orthogonal to both of them. Given two vectors $a$ and $b$ over a basis $e_{(k)}$,
$
\begin{align*}
a\times b=\epsilon_{ijk}a_ib_je_{(k)}
\end{align*}
$
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol. Look this up if you're unfamiliar, it's super cool. Anyways, after you calculate the vector, divide by the norm and you're done.